# GCD( LCM(a,b) , LCM(a,c) ) = LCM(a, GCD(b,c)) , How?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I actually asked this question already once [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3785014/gcd-lcma-b-lcma-c-lcmb-gcdb-c-why), but I marked it answered by mistake and it was also titled wrong. I wanted to ask where I went wrong in the following lines and what should be the correct way to arrive at the conclusion. I suspect its line 3.
$$
GCD\bigl(( LCM(a,b) , LCM(a,c)\bigr) 
\\\\=> a \times GCD\left( \frac{b}{GCD(a,b)} , \frac{c}{GCD(a,c)} \right)
\\\\=> \frac{a \times GCD(b,c)}{GCD\bigl( GCD(a,b) , GCD(a,c)\bigr)}
\\\\=> \frac{a \times GCD(b,c)}{GCD(a,b,c)}
\\\\=> \frac{a \times GCD(b,c)}{GCD\bigl(a, GCD(b,c)\bigr)}
\\\\=> LCM\bigl(a , GCD(b,c)\bigr)
$$

Comment: I asked how, not why, I want to know how I should proceed from the second line to arrive at the conclusion

Comment: Should the title say LCM(a,GCD(b,c))?

Comment: @KentaS yes, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT:

Use factorization. Let $a=p_1^{d_1}p_2^{d_2}\cdots p_i^{d_i}$, $b=p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_i^{e_i}$, and $b=p_1^{f_1}p_2^{f_2}\cdots p_i^{f_i}$ (Some of the exponents may be $0$.)

Then, note that $\text{lcm}(a,b)=p_1^{\max\{d_1,e_1\}}p_2^{\max\{d_2,e_2\}}\cdots p_i^{\max\{d_i,e_i\}}$ and $\text{gcd}(a,b)=p_1^{\min\{d_1,e_1\}}p_2^{\min\{d_2,e_2\}}\cdots p_i^{\min\{d_i,e_i\}}$. Thus, to prove the equation, it is enough to prove $\min\{\max\{d_k,e_k\},\max\{d_k,f_k\}\}=\max\{d_k,\min\{e_k,f_k\}\}$ for each $k$.